# T-SQL XQuery for returning a result row per matching XML value for each nested element

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Given a XML data typed column x in table y with values such as:

```
<a>
<b>
<c>1</c>
<c>2</c>
<c>3</c>
</b>
</a>
```

How can I obtain a result set with T-SQL XQuery such that one row is returned per `<c>` element value?
Let's say table y also has column z that contains the number of `<c>` elements in column x - just so we have an additional column to return.

The best we could come up with thus far was:

```
select 
z, 
cvalues = x.query('data(a/b/c)')
from y
```

The above however will return one row per row in y and have a white space separated list of the values for the `<c>` elements in column cvalues.

How can we get a result set such as:

```
z cvalues
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

instead of what we get now:

```
z cvalues
3 1 2 3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` combined with [`nodes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx):

```
SELECT 
  z, 
  cvalues = s.c.value('.', 'int')
FROM y
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('//c') AS s(c);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/405434)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══╦═════════╗
║ z ║ cvalues ║
╠═══╬═════════╣
║ 3 ║       1 ║
║ 3 ║       2 ║
║ 3 ║       3 ║
╚═══╩═════════╝
```

Keep in mind that:

`//c` match all `c` xml element no matter where it is in hierarchy

`/a/b/c` will match `c` xml element that is nested inside `a` and `b`

Comment: Very good! Added bonus for the part on matching. Excited to learn more XQuery: seems it can be very useful indeed.